# Help me understand what constitutes spam - conflicting signals from flag resolution and audit question

Tags: support, review-audits, spam

Note:  I am not disputing anything in this question, I'm asking for help.

A week or so ago I flagged the following answer as spam:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722649/continuous-integration-in-nodejs/17352370#17352370

The flag was rejected and the system kept reminding me of that every time I flagged another post for a few days.

Just now, I was doing low quality post reviews, and I saw an answer that looked to me like spam.  I was about to act on that basis, but then I remembered my rejected flag.  Sure, the link in this post looked like spam, but based on the content of the post, it looked like spam that actually would answer the question.  That was a similar situation the answer I had flagged as spam but had my flag rejected.  So I figured this type of spam was acceptable and accepted the post.

Turns out, it was an audit, which I failed.  To add insult to injury, the Answer section on the audit failure page was blank, so I couldn't review the answer in detail.  I haven't been able to figure out how to find it again since I left that page.

So - any chance a high rep user can see the audit question I failed and explain the difference between that post and the post which I flagged as spam?  Or can anyone at least tell me how to find my failed audit question so I can look at it or link to it in this post?  I'd really appreciate it, as it will help me in the future with appropriate flagging and reviews.

Comment: Here's a link to the review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4780103 - you can't see the post since it is deleted, you only get to see it during the actual "audit". But you should be able to get to the question via the links in the review.

Comment: Well, though it is written like an advertisement, I guess it does answer the question.  The *question itself* is obviously off-topic, so let's close that?

Comment: @Mat Thanks.  That was exactly what I saw after failing the audit, along with the admonishment to review the (blank) answer carefully to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Honestly, looking at the CI post, it really does ***look*** like spam, but I guess it was intentionally created to look like an advertisement. As far as I can tell, the guy who posted it doesn't actually work for the company, it looks like he was just being creative.

Comment: @Cupcake So part of the definition of spam is that it has to be posted by someone with a conflict of interest?  That certainly might be a difference.  I hate following apparent spam links because of the potential for a virus, though - what happens if I skip an audit question?

Comment: @Warren Dew: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160805/are-review-audit-pass-fail-decisions-ever-triggered-by-skip - skipping isn't a problem (you're likely to get another audit very soon afterwards though I believe)